# Resolve URI failed error on bad bitmap

Tags: java, android

I am trying to decode  Base64 strings and some text to a bitmap and load it to a listview using hashmap. the text are displayed on the listview but not the bit map and i am getting "resolveuri failed on bad bitmap" exception..

## MainActivity

```
   try {
                // Getting JSON Array from URL
             details = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Root);
                for(int i = 0; i < details.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = details.getJSONObject(i);

                 //Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String branch = c.getString(TAG_Branch);
               String address = c.getString(TAG_Add);
                String uname = c.getString(TAG_User);
                String photo = c.getString(TAG_Photo);
                 System.out.println(photo);
               //decoding the base64 image to an png format

                byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(photo, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
                //ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
              // image.setImageBitmap(
                    // BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length)
                //);

               System.out.println();

                HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                map.put(TAG_Branch, branch);
               map.put(TAG_Add, address);
               map.put(TAG_User, uname);
               map.put(TAG_Photo, bitmap);
              oslist.add(map);

              //String.valueOf(TAG_Photo
                //,R.id.imageView1
                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this,      oslist,
                        R.layout.list_activity,
                        new String[] { TAG_Branch,TAG_Add, TAG_User,TAG_Photo }, new int[] {
                                R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3,R.id.imageView1});
```

## logcat

Comment: it because `SimpleAdapter` ... [it just "know" how to bind `int`(resource id) or `String`(url) to ImageView](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.java#L188) .... you need to use custom ViewBinder ... because now it trying to use `bitmap.toString()` as url ...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/9b514a4842f547ddefb2 ... of course it will only resolve this problem ... storing Bitmaps in data elements is not a good idea ... it will cause OOME sooner or later

Comment: Thank you so much Selvin. I used the SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder and a out of memory exception raised..

Comment: using base64 is a bad, bad ... you should rather use some url and use existing loader library (or at least save decoded base64 as temp files and use loader too)... but here is a quick fix( **you shouldn't use it in production code** ) https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/916ea634693fda05545b

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to get bitmap from internet not use Asynctask. This is bad idea.
You can follow Google develop tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: i dont have other option rather than parsing the JSON and getting the bitmap

Comment: hehe ... getting bitmaps from internet ... bad idea ... heh... maybe she did it wrong but this is not an answer to this question ...

Comment: #Selvin: I am sory for my wrong. I think get bitmap from internet without Asynctask/ Thread/ Runable is bad idea.

#Elizabeth: I think you should use Asynctask for getting bitmap from internet and use BitmapOption for decode bitmap from source